# Importing specific profiles from AD

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, import

I want to import accounts in specific OU's and not the whole Active Directory.
I have created the connection to AD and everything is working well.
I'm sure it is possible to import specific accounts in specific OU's using the 'User Filter' and creating new query clauses, here lies my problem. I have no idea on the syntax I should use.

Any help would be great, even a link to a good article/blog.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [some info here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/827754) along with some additional links on the LDAP filters.

Here is another blog I found helpful: [MOSS Profile Search LDAP query to remove disabled and service accounts](http://blogs.msdn.com/sumanc/archive/2007/06/28/moss-profile-search-ldap-query-to-remove-disabled-and-service-accounts.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough I was listening to a podcast from Todd Klindt yesterday and he was talking about a client which wanted to remove profiles for Conference and Meeting Rooms from the SharePoint User Profile Import Process.

He suggested using the AD Users and Computers MSC and using the AD saved query tool which sits at the top. I do remember using it a few years ago when I was playing around with MS Exchange. Anyway I will leave it to him to take you through it:-

[Using ADUC to configure SharePoint Profile Import](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=177)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.  I had the AD folks populate the EmployeeID field in AD with the Employee's ID from our SAP.  I then added a filter to synchronize only active employees.

UserProfile Synchronization Connection Filters

1. User is Not Disabled
2. User has an E-Mail Address
3. User has an Employee ID

(&(objectClass=User)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(mail=*)(employeeID=**))

Just remove that last asterisk from employeeID=

Bismarck